# Unity: Several gameObjects in an array(?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

i'm making this beat 'em up game on unity that has the following mechanism: when the player's collider hits an enemy's:

```
public GameObject obj;
...

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider){
obj=collider.gameObject;
}
```

Then, when the player attacks, if its distance to the obj is small enough, the enemy receives damage:

```
void hit(){
    if(kicked&&close){  //if he is kicking and is close enough
        obj.GetComponent<health>().DealDamage(damage); //this is inside a try/catch, just in case obj=null
(...)
}
```

The problem is, if 2 enemies touch the player, only the last one will be assigned to the variable obj, so he will take the hit alone, which i don't want to happen.

Any suggestions? Should i replace

```
GameObject obj;
```

with an array? How is that?

and then, on the OnTriggerEnter method, add objects to the array? (how to do that?)

Comment: An array's size is immutable, and you need a data structure whose size can dynamically shrink and grow. Use a `List` instead.

Comment: what if i use an array larger than i will ever need?

Comment: Alternative approach - use a method like `Physics.OverlapSphere()` to check at the time of attack which enemies are within the player attack's range, then damage them accordingly (if any).

Comment: @DavidSpira It would depend on if you could definitively say what would be "more than you will ever need". I wouldn't recommend just making a 10,000-length array because that would be insanely wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to have your player holding a trigger box. When the enemies enter the trigger box, they get added to a collection and removed when exiting:

```
public class PlayerAttack:MonoBehaviour
{
    private HashSet<Enemy> list = null;
    private void Awake(){ this.list = new HashSet<Enemy>(); }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
         Enemy enemy = col.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
         if(enemy != null)
         {
             this.list.Add(enemy);  
         } 
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
         Enemy enemy = col.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
         if(enemy != null && this.list.Contains(enemy) == true)
         { 
             this.list.Remove(enemy);  
         } 
    }
    public void OnAttack()
    {
         foreach(Enemy enemy in this.list)
         { 
            enemy.GetComponent<Health>.DealDamage(damage); 
         }
    }
}
```

OnAttack is your attack method that will iterate through all close enemies. 
HashSet is a good candidate here as it won't add twice the same item so no risk of seeing an enemy getting multiple hits.

Comment: i tried this and i got this error message
Assets/Scripts/movement.cs(16,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HashSet`1' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

@Everts

this is the line 16
       private HashSet<Enemy> list = null;

Comment: by the way, i'm using sublime text, but i realize now that monodevelop does not recognize HashSet. Maybe i have to import something first?

Comment: When this kind of things occurs, your first solution is right click on the error then Resolve. It will most likely propose to add some using directive. In Visual Studio you can place the cursor on the error and Ctrl + . (not sure that shortcut works in MonoDevelop). In the case of HashSet, you are likely to be missing System.Collections.Generic

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to solve the problem. The damage never gets to be assigned.

```
private HashSet<Enemy> list = null;

private void Awake(){this.list = new HashSet<Enemy>();}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){

     Enemy enemy = col.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
     print(enemy); // this occurs
     if(enemy != null && this.list.Contains(enemy) == true)
     { 
        print(enemy); // this never occurs
         this.list.Remove(enemy);  
     } 
    }
    }


void hit(){      
    print("hit"); // this occurs

    foreach(Enemy enemy in this.list)
     {   // this never occurs
        enemy.GetComponent<health>().DealDamage(damage); 
     }
```

@Everts

Answer (score -2):

You have the lists of all objects on screen as enemies, trees, boxes etc.
And in endless cycle you do some actions with all objects:

```
while(true)
{
    // Here non combat characters do something.
    foreach(NonCombatCharacter character in NonCombatCharacters)
    {
        switch(character.Type)
        {
            case tinyBird: character.DoAction(Actions.Fly); break;
            case ...
            default:break;
        }
    }
    // Here your combat character aka enemies
    foreach(CombatCharacter character in CombatCharacters)
    {
        // Here you do your combat logic, cheks and etc.
    }
    // And then you player character change the world model, here you
    // process all player action such as changing position, losing hp.
    // And then world keep lifecycle again
}
```

EDIT: So there is global arrays foreach object. In unity you got them too, even if you dont create the array.
Here you go:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html
Use documentation, most of common answers are all there.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Actually answer if you "get the point". This explain basics. I am edit answer for better understanding.

Comment: Like Evan said, this doesn't answer OP's question. The array isn't for keeping track of all entities in the entire world. It's a reference array for tracking and processing the latest object collisions. Not only would this method be an insane amount of overkill, but it also doesn't solve his problem. (Also `while(true)`? Seriously?)